# Event Study from DID regression using coefplot

Tags: stata, coefplot

I am trying to create a event study plot that give me yearly average treatment effects on the treated on a business law on the average number of property firms relative to a control state where the business law is not in effect. Where am I going wrong with my code?

```
xtset county_id year

gen post = year >= sbdcopen
gen treated_post = treated * post

* Run the fixed-effects regression
xtreg prop_firms treated_post##c.year, fe

* Store the estimated coefficients
estimates store event_study

* Generate variable for the difference from mean
matrix mean_b = e(b)
gen diff_from_mean = prop_firms - mean_b[1, 1]

* Create coefplot for the event study
coefplot (diff_from_mean, label("Excess Prop Firms")) ///
    xline(0) ylabel("Difference from Mean") ///
    xlabel("Year relative to treatment") ///
    title("Event Study: Excess Prop Firms Over Time")

estimation result diff_from_mean not found
```

Comment: Hello! Maybe someone is able/willing to help you based on the information given, but you are more likely to get a helpful response if you describe what error you get. A reproducible example is also helpful. Also, SO is a forum for coding questions, so if your question is about the statistical validity of your approach then there are other forums you are more likely to get help.

Comment: I can only endorse @TheIceBear. It's just about possible that someone who does this kind of thing routinely can read your code and work out what it would produce and see what the problem is, but without (a) a reproducible example (b) any error report this is likely doomed to get no response.

Comment: Thank you the error code is at the bottom. estimation result diff_from_mean not found meaning that the diff_from_mean results are not stored for some reason. Is not about statistical validity I have a nice panel dataset with external validity.

Comment: Well, two experienced users didn't notice your error report, so read that as you will.  It is customary to report the error code, which is a number like 198,

Answer (score 0):

You have more control on the event study plot if you generate dummies for treated units for each year yourself. See example below:

```
forvalues i = 2004(2)2020 {
    gen dum_`i' = (year == `i')
    gen did_`i' = dum_`i' * treated
    drop dum_`i'
}
gen constant = 1
eststo event_interest: reghdfe outcomevar did_2004-did_2006 constant did_2010-did_2020, absorb(i.year i.county) vce(cluster county)

coefplot event_interest, omitted vertical yline(0, lcolor(black)) xline(4, lpattern(dash) lcolor(gray*0.5)) keep(did_* constant)
```

In this example, the treatment happens in 2010 (shown as `xline(4)`) and I replace the first pre-treatment period (2008) by a `constant` in order to avoid losing this in the coefplot.

Edit: variable names

Comment: OK, but how does this answer the question?